# How to navigate to exact page opened in previous session in Selenium when switching between Sikuli and Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Problem Statement: We have to automate a scenario where action traverse between windows and web based pages.

We use SikuliX and Selenium 3.141.

Issue is I always land on main home page but the requirement is to land on previously launched web page.

1.Open webpage1 (main home page)

2.Perform action and close webpage.

3.Focus on windows action (Sikuli), perform and close.

4.Switch back to webpage > opens main home page, create some object (lands into app home page) and close.

5.Switch to windows action (Sikuli), perform and close.

6.Lastly, switch back to webpage,expectation is to land on 'app home page' but I land on main home page.

Is there a possibility to land into app page or subpages in selenium than main home page always.

Please review snippet.

```
'''//Open selenium
   commonLibrary.login(); //opens webpage1
   commonLibrary.getCookie();
   driver.close(); //close webpage of selenium
   //Close selenium

//Open Sikuli 
s.click("C:\\APMWS\\testmvnproject\\src\\imagelibrary\\images\\start.png");  //Close Sikuli

//Open selenium
 commonLibrary.setBrowser("browser");
 commonLibrary.navigateToUrl("url");
 commonLibrary.setCookie(); 
 commonLibrary.navigateToUrl("url"); //again set url with new cookies


driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'View My Company')]")).click(); //opens webpage 2
commonLibrary.getCookie();
 driver.close();
//Close selenium

//Open Sikuli
s.click("C:\\APMWS\\testmvnproject\\src\\imagelibrary\\images\\close.png");
//Close Sikuli


//Open selenium
commonLibrary.setBrowser("browser");
commonLibrary.navigateToUrl("url");
commonLibrary.setCookie(); //we need to send previously stored cookies which we collected and stored before closing browser
commonLibrary.navigateToUrl("url"); //again set url with new cookies

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Organizational Expenses')]")).click(); //this action exists on webpage 2 above, but I land on webpage 1
//Close selenium
'''
```

Usecase:
1. Login to webpage and store cookie information.

2. Close the session.
3. Switch to windows action in Sikulix, perform some action and close.
4. Now, again switch to webpage by reading cookies stored.
5. It directly goes to Main home page without logging-in.
6. Perform some create action of part which will take the control of selenium to Part home page.
7. Store cookies and close the session, switch to Sikuli, perform action and close.
8. Now, restore cookies and launch webpage.

Expected Result: Browser should open with part home page(sub page).

Actual Result: Browsers opens to main home page.

Comment: My guess is that you will have to either store the relevant cookies before ending session 1 and restore them before starting session 2 or just open a preexisting profile when running both.

Comment: Thanks @JeffC. I want something like RequestURL which will take to exact page. Cookies remain same, I noticed.